# Getting specific value from DataGrid

Tags: .net, mysql, datagrid

Can't figure out why am I not able to call this line of code?

```
MsgBox(SAMPLEIDDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).ToString())
```

I get the following error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

How is that possible if my table is as follows:

ID      First Name    Last Name
0   Guy       TheGuy
1   John          Smith
2   Jim       Earthworm
3   Nathan        Drake

My Table Design is as follows:

ID  int 25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   -1  0
First Name  varchar 25  0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       latin1  latin1_swedish_ci       0   0
Last Name   varchar 25  0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       latin1  latin1_swedish_ci       0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with SelectedRows and so if you have no rows selected it will give you that exception!

Try just Rows..

Comment: Thanks that works! I have another question. MsgBox(SAMPLEIDDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells("First Name").ToString()) Why when I specify Column directly it does not work?

Comment: MsgBox(SAMPLEIDDataGridView.Rows(0).Cells("First Name").ToString())  This line gives me the following exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Column named First Name cannot be found.

Comment: Oh it should be Rows[0].Cells["First Name"].. Use SQUARE brackets.. Did that even compile?!!!

Comment: Also don't forget to mark my answer as "correct" by checking the tick mark beside it. You could also "vote" on answers.. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does compile gives me no errors. Errors out only while running. I am using Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Basic.

Comment: Oh it's VB. I don't use VB sorry! You can try Rows(0).Cells("First Name").Value.ToString()..

Comment: Yes that is what I have now. Will let me get the value as long as I use Rows(0).Cells(0) but as soon as I put column name as string it gives me an error. Thanks anyway.